# Кодировки Java при работе с консолью

Tags: java

Моя маленькая программа работает в консоли и читает данные из файла и показывает пользователю условно говоря и при соблюдении некоторых условий, записывает в него данные.

Когда запускаю через IDE, то работает всё отлично, но когда запускаю через консоль свой .jar файл, то всё что он прочитал из файла коверкается (примерно так: ЏалЈ вм бв®п).

Я так понимаю дело в кодировках, хотя я пытался решить эту проблему до её появления и чтение запись проводил со следующими параметрами:

```
BufferedWriter bwHabitList = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(HabitListFile), "UTF8"));

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(HabitListFile), "UTF8"));
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где искать проблему?

Comment: Правильно писать "UTF-8"

Comment: а лучше использовать уже существующие константы что-то вроде 
`java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

Comment: @zolt Поменял, не помогло, при работе с консолью всё так же пишет непонятные знаки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось очень простым (не знаю почему никто не смог помочь, но спустя несколько дней поиска, нашёл сам ответ).

Дело было в том, что консоль работает в кодировке CP866 и соответственно если пытаться вводить данные в иной кодировке, то они искажаются.

Проверить кодировку консоли можно прописав в консоль команду chcp (консоль должна быть запущена от имени администратора).